# How to use sbt 'ProjectRef' with multiple Scala versions

Tags: sbt

`sbt` is [able to pull in source dependencies](http://blog.xebia.com/git-subproject-compile-time-dependencies-in-sbt/), using `dependsOn( ProjectRef(uri("git://github.com/..."), "xyz")`, but such dependencies are only available for the default Scala version of the dependency, even when it does support cross compilation.

I think this is a deficiency / bug of `sbt` but thought to open this question in case others have stumbled on this / know ways around it.

---

#### Edit

Opened [an issue](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/2901) at sbt's GitHub concerning this

Have found two alternative workarounds:

- prepare a separate tag (e.g. `x.y.z-2.11`) at the dependency, where `scalaVersion` is temporarily changed to the secondary one
- `sbt +update`; after this all works normally

The first one means extra manual labour, whereas the second one is simply a bit surprising.